# nodelist sometimes loads after the function is finished

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue where I sometimes am able to load the nodelist before it is being called but at the same time it sometimes loads after it is being called(Causing an error of the list being undefined).

[This is what I wish would appear all the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN7Pa.png)

[Sorry, this is the right image now. This is the error I receive sometimes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3jn2.png)

[I believe this is the issue but I do not know how to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02i7W.png)

I have done some searching online and I think it is related to the code being async or synchrous..(I have not learned about this so I am unsure if I am correct). Here's my code. Context: the `getNeighbourhoodData()` is being onloaded to the body of my html page.

```
function getNeighbourhoodData(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', neighbourhood_url, true);

    //This function will be called when data returns from the web api
    request.onload = function() {
    //get all the restaurant records into our neighbourhood array
    neighbourhood_array = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    //get User data
    displayNeighbourhoods();
    };
    //This command starts the calling of the restaurant web api
    request.send();
}
function displayNeighbourhoods() {
    var list = document.getElementsByName("neiList");

    console.log(list);
    num=0;
    alphabet_array=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
    console.log(alphabet_array);
    for (var count = 0; count < neighbourhood_array.length; count++) {    
        var neighbourhood = neighbourhood_array[count].Neighbourhood;
        if(neighbourhood_array[count].Neighbourhood.startsWith(alphabet_array[num])== true ){
        var cell = '<li><a class="a--grey" href="/restByNeighbourhood.html" onclick="getName(this)" name="Paya Lebar">'+ neighbourhood +'</a></li>';
        list[num].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cell);
            if(count >= neighbourhood_array.length-1 && num <= 25){
                num+=1;
                count=-1;
                console.log(num);
            }
        } 
        else if(count >= neighbourhood_array.length - 1 && num <= 25){
            num+=1;
            count=-1; 
            console.log(num);

        }
        else if(num >= 26){
            break;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }




    }    

}
```

Comment: The error appears in the displayRestaurant function. Please include this one aswell

Comment: Oh no i attached the wrong image! Ill change it as soon as i get back haha

Comment: @Tracer69 I've attached the right image now. So sorry.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is Single threaded, which means only one thing can happen at a time. However, with async calls you can "act" like a multy-threaded language.

For example the build-in fetch() funktion returns a Promise that you can await.

```
async function loadURLodContent() {  //
  const result = await fetch(/* url-path */);
}
```

So you can await Promises and write async funktions that return promises. 
But this topic isnt an easy one. I'd really recomend getting into Promises and Async calls as soon as possible because you're gonna encounter them if you develop in the Web sooner or later.

But to your Problem.... at least from my point of view you're not giving enough information. Tracer69 hase a good proposal for that in the comments.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed i attached the wrong image for the error, ill change it soon